# Set DependencyProperty from reflection in wpf - type convertion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection, dependency-properties

I have some fun with WPF and I decided to build a library with custom implementation of attached triggers (similar to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll), but my own.

I have a class `TriggerAction` which represents an action invoked by Trigger. I want to begin with something really easy like setting the background of the button while the user click it.

I have already written some working code for example EventTrigger class, but I have one problem with my `SetterTriggerAction`. I have two dependency properties `PropertyName` which represents the name of property which should be set an a `Value` property. In the Invoke method I try to set property with a defined value.

Here is the code:

```
internal override void Invoke(DependencyObject obj)
{
        if (obj == null) 
            return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName)) 
            return;

        PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (property == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cannot find property {0} for type {1}.", PropertyName, obj.GetType());
            return;
        }

        MethodInfo setMethod = property.GetSetMethod();

        if (setMethod == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The property {0} does not have set method.", PropertyName);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            setMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { Value });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception caught {0} with message {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

My second attempt:

```
internal override void Invoke(DependencyObject obj)
{
        if (obj == null) 
            return;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName)) return;
        FieldInfo property = obj.GetType().GetField(PropertyName+"Property", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        if (property == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cannot find dependency property {0} for type {1}.", PropertyName+"Property", obj.GetType());
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            DependencyProperty dp = property.GetValue(obj) as DependencyProperty;
            if(dp == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cannot get DependencyProperty {0}", PropertyName + "Property");
                return;
            }
            obj.SetValue(dp, Value);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception caught {0} with message {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In xaml I wrote:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Click">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <i:SetterTriggerAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

So when I click the button I want to make its background red. However both versions of Invoke method suffers from convertion issue and in my output window I get a message that "Red" is not valid value for property Background (because it is treated like string not a Brush!). 
Is there any way to convert a value from xaml (string "Red") to a valid Brush value? I would like to have as general way of converting properties as possible.

I consider that something similar to what I want to achieve is done when xaml is parsed and properties of controls are set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a string to a Brush you could use the default type converter class [`BrushConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushconverter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var redBrush = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Red");
```

Comment: I have already cope with that problem. The solution is to get property type and check whether it is marked with TypeConverterAttribute. Then dynamically create instance of the converter and call ConvertFrom method. There is a lot of `TypeConverter` classes in `PresentationCore` assembly